# JS - array[index].length reads as undefined, even though it prints in function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript and can't figure out why I get an error in line 6 (cannot read property "length" of undefined) if that same property (the length of each word in the index) prints correctly below it.

```
function findShort(s){
  var inpt = s.split(' ');
  var final = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i <= inpt.length; i++) {
    if (inpt[i].length <= final) {
      console.log(inpt[i].length);
      final += inpt[i].length;
    }
  }
  return final;
}

findShort("this is a test");
```

So, I'll get:

```
// -> 4
// -> 2
// -> 1
// -> 4
// -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at findShort:6:16
    at eval:14:1
    at eval
    at n.<anonymous>
```

Comment: Should be `<` not `<=` in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you are running off the end of your array. You need to iterate until it's < the length, not <=.

```js
function findShort(s){
  var inpt = s.split(' ');
  var final = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < inpt.length; i++) { // < not <=
    if (inpt[i].length <= final) {
      console.log(inpt[i].length);
      final += inpt[i].length;
    }
  }
  return final;
}

findShort("this is a test");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an error.
Try `for (var i = 0; i < inpt.length; i++)` because your indexaton is less that inpt.length

Comment: How does this differ from @Jordan S's answer?